# is this valid for getting input state value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to build reusable form and input components and so far was able to achieve what I am after, here is how they are used in a LoginPage component

```
import React from 'react'
import classNames from 'classnames/bind'
import styles from './style.scss'
import Form from 'components/Form'
import Input from 'components/Input'

const cx = classNames.bind(styles)

export default class LoginPage extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.loginUser = this.loginUser.bind(this)
  }

  loginUser () {
    console.log(`
      Email: ${this.refs.email.state.value} Password: ${this.refs.password.state.value}
    `)
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <main className={cx('LoginPage')}>
        <div className={cx('container')}>
          <Form onSubmit={this.loginUser}>
            <Input type='email' placeholder='email' ref='email' />
            <Input type='password' placeholder='password' ref='password' />
            <Input type='submit' value='Log in' />
          </Form>
        </div>
      </main>
    )
  }
}
```

The question I'm asking is if using `this.refs.email.state.value` is a valid approach to this, to get that input components value from its state?

Comment: This might be overkill for your situation, but FYI there is a library that helps with this sort of thing: https://www.npmjs.com/package/valuelink

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need `refs` for your case. Remember that they should not be used when the normal data flow of `props` can accomplish the same. From [the docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html#cautions)

> If you have not programmed several apps with React, your first
>   inclination is usually going to be to try to use refs to "make things
>   happen" in your app. If this is the case, take a moment and think more
>   critically about where state should be owned in the component
>   hierarchy. **Often, it becomes clear that the proper place to "own" that
>   state is at a higher level in the hierarchy.** Placing the state there
>   often eliminates any desire to use refs to "make things happen" –
>   instead, the data flow will usually accomplish your goal.

Another warning sign should be that [string `refs` are considered legacy](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html#the-ref-string-attribute) and will be deprecated.

A better and safer way of achieving what you need is to handle the input change separately and keep that in the local component state. So your code would look something like this:

```
// ...imports...

const cx = classNames.bind(styles)

const initialState = {
  eamil: '',
  password: '',
};

export default class LoginPage extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.loginUser = this.loginUser.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    let nextState = {};
    nextState[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
    this.setState(nextState);
  }

  loginUser () {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(`
      Email: ${this.state.email} Password: ${this.state.password}
    `)
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <main className={cx('LoginPage')}>
        <div className={cx('container')}>
          <Form onSubmit={this.loginUser}>
            <Input 
              type='email' 
              value={this.state.email} 
              placeholder='email' 
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
            <Input 
              type='password' 
              value={this.state.password} 
              placeholder='password' 
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
            <Input type='submit' value='Log in' />
          </Form>
        </div>
      </main>
    )
  }
}
```

Here the state is at the top of the form component. You could make it even more general and have a `form` Redux store with its own actions and reducers, but it should give you an idea.

Let me know if you have questions on the code.

Comment: No worries, have fun!

Answer (score 0):

Please use this.refs.email.value instead of this.refs.email.state.value.
Yes it is a standard way in react

OR

You can attach eventListener onClick and keep email in state.

```
export default class LoginPage extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.loginUser = this.loginUser.bind(this)
  }

  loginUser () {
    console.log(`
      Email: ${this.refs.email.value} Password: ${this.refs.password.value}
    `)
  }

  changeEmail(event) {
   this.setState({
       email: event.target.value
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <main className={cx('LoginPage')}>
        <div className={cx('container')}>
          <Form onSubmit={this.loginUser}>
            <Input type='email' value={this.state.value} onClick={this.changeEmail} placeholder='email' ref='email' />
            <Input type='password' placeholder='password' ref='password' />
            <Input type='submit' value='Log in' />
          </Form>
        </div>
      </main>
    )
  }
}
```